# Sum column data if data are of same type

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table with the tabular structure and table name is advance:

```
Column  Type    Null    Default
AdvanceID   int(11) No  
EmployeeID  int(11) Yes NULL
Amount  int(11) Yes NULL
Month   int(11) Yes NULL
Year    year(4) No  
Rule    tinyint(1)  Yes NULL
IsPaid  tinyint(4)  No  0
CreatedDate timestamp   No  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
CreatedBy   int(11) No  1
UpdatedDate timestamp   Yes NULL
UpdatedBy   int(11) Yes NULL
IsActive    int(11) No  1
IsDeleted   int(11) No  0
```

In here the advance as a loan are saved with every month deduction in a single row.
[image: This is the screenshot of the data in the database]

This is the screenshot of the data in the database
Now what I need is if the EmployeeID matches the Amount should be automatically sum up to those row only which has IsPaid 0.
I want that as a query output.
I tried to use DISTINCT(EmployeeID) but I could not sum the amount if the EmployeeID match.
I am in need of that to optimize my work and minimize my server-side code.

Comment: hint: SUM(Amount) and GROUP BY EmployeeID, IsPaid

Comment: Read up on aggregate functions and group by.https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this query:-

```
SELECT  EmployeeID,SUM(Amount) as totalAmount 
FROM loan    // your tablename
WHERE isPaid=0
GROUP BY EmployeeID;
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by using aggregate function and ORDER BY:

```
SELECT EmployeeID, SUM(Amount) as Amount FROM advance WHERE IsPaid = 0 GROUP BY EmployeeID
```